# Does 'tf.assign' return its argument?

Tags: variables, tensorflow, variable-assignment

The Tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) says that `tf.assign(ref, ...)` returns `ref`, but it appears instead (not surprisingly) to return a `Tensor` (attached to the `assign` op):

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

Q = tf.Variable(tf.constant(range(1, 12)))
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
qop = tf.assign(Q, tf.zeros(Q.shape, tf.int32))#.eval()

print(Q.eval())
print(qop.eval())
print(Q.eval())
```

produces

```
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

demonstrating that the argument `Q` and what's returned `qop` behave differently (and that `Q` is unchanged until `qop` is executed).

Is the return value of `tf.assign` described correctly in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation of Tensorflow about operations.  `tf.assign` returns an `Operation`, which **represents a graph node** that performs computations on tensors.  You use the operations to compose a graph of computations.  Those computations actually occur at a later time, when you call `eval` on any of the operations of the graph.

In your example `qop` is the definition of an operation that assigns zeros to variable `Q`.  The graph of your example would look something like `Q --> qep`.  For pedagogical purposes, let's change the order of your code to something like this:

```
Q = tf.Variable(tf.constant(range(1, 12)))

Q.eval()  # Error: Variable has not been initalized.

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

Q.eval()  # Output: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11], dtype=int32)

qop = tf.assign(Q, tf.zeros(Q.shape, tf.int32))

Q.eval() # Output: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11], dtype=int32)

qop.eval()

Q.eval() # Output array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
```

The first time you evaluate `Q` you get an error, because the variable represented by Q does not contain anything in it yet.  But after you run `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` the error goes away. That is because that line of code runs an operation that initializes all the global variables of the current graph.  When you run `Q.eval()` after defining the `qop` operation, `Q` still has the same values, because operation `qop` was defined, but not yet executed.  Once you execute `qop` (`qop.eval`) is that the value of the variable represnted by `Q` changes.

Comment: So the docs are wrong: `tf.assign(ref, ...` does not return `ref` but returns a new op (not surprisingly). Right?

Comment: Let me check the docs. They are at least ambiguous. In one part of the documentation they say the following: "Update `ref` by assigning `value` to it. That is what the operation tf.assign does once it is executed.  They also say that it returns the same as `ref`.  If you do `type(Q)` and `type(qop)` you will notice that they have different types.  But then the types and shapes of `Q.eval()` and `qop.eval()` will be the same.

Comment: The first part is correct, but: "Returns: Same as 'ref'" is clearly wrong, and it goes on to be even more explicitly wrong with: "Returned as a convenience for operations that want to use the new value after the variable has been reset." Right? It should say "Returns: The assignment operation, which updates the value of 'ref' when executed". No?